# two columns with answers package

Tags: multicol, answers

I want to use `multicol` package in `answers` package for my text book. How can I fix this problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}
\setlist[enumerate]{labelsep=10pt,leftmargin=45pt}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label= $\arabic*.$}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{leftmargin=*,label=\theenumi$\arabic*$),ref=\theenumi$\arabic*$)}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\newtheorem{exer}{Exercise}[section]
\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{solution}{Solution}{ans}
\renewcommand{\Solutionlabel}[1]{#1}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[exer1.1]
\begin{exer}\label{exer1.1}\mbox{ }
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First problem
    \begin{solution}
    Sol. of first problem
    \end{solution} 
    \item Second problem
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \item Sub second problem
    \begin{solution}
        Sol. of 2.1
    \end{solution} 
    \item Sub second problem
    \begin{solution}
        Sol. of 2.2
    \end{solution}  
    \item Sub second problem
    \begin{solution}
        Sol. of 2.3
    \end{solution} 
    \item Sub second problem
    \begin{solution}
        Sol. of 2.4
    \end{solution}  
\end{multicols}     
\end{enumerate} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{exer}
\Closesolutionfile{ans}

\bigskip

\section*{\centering Solutions of Chapter \thechapter}

\subsection*{Solutions of Exercise \ref{exer1.1}}
\input{exer1.1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: you want solutions  output like problemes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you should add `multicols` environment to your answers file, here the `mtmulticols` environment is defined to do this

**Edit: Updated** the idea is to input

```
\Writetofile{ans}{\string\begin{multicols}{2}}
```

just befor first solution (short ones) and

```
\Writetofile{ans}{\string\end{multicols}}
```

after the last one

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem,calc}
\setlist[enumerate]{labelsep=10pt,leftmargin=45pt}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label= $\arabic*.$}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{leftmargin=*,label=\theenumi$\arabic*$),ref=\theenumi$\arabic*$)}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\newtheorem{exer}{Exercise}[section]
\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{solution}{Solution}{ans}
\renewcommand{\Solutionlabel}[1]{#1}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newenvironment{mtmulticols}[1]{%
\Writetofile{ans}{\string\begin{multicols}{#1}}
\begin{multicols}{#1}}{\end{multicols}%
\Writetofile{ans}{\string\end{multicols}}}

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[exer1.1]
\begin{exer}\label{exer1.1}\mbox{ }
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First problem
    \begin{solution}
    Sol. of first problem
    \end{solution} 
    \item Second problem
\begin{enumerate}
\begin{mtmulticols}{2}
    \item Sub second problem
    \begin{solution}
        Sol. of 2.1
    \end{solution} 
    \item Sub second problem
    \begin{solution}
        Sol. of 2.2
    \end{solution}  
    \item Sub second problem
    \begin{solution}
        Sol. of 2.3
    \end{solution} 
    \item Sub second problem
    \begin{solution}
        Sol. of 2.4
    \end{solution}  
\end{mtmulticols}     
\end{enumerate} 

    \item problem in one column very very very very very long

\Writetofile{ans}{\string\begin{multicols}{2}}
    \begin{solution}
       short  Sol. to very long
    \end{solution}

    \item last problem in one column very very very very very long


    \begin{solution}
       short  Sol. to very long
    \end{solution}
\Writetofile{ans}{\string\end{multicols}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{exer}
\Closesolutionfile{ans}

\bigskip

\section*{\centering Solutions of Chapter \thechapter}

\subsection*{Solutions of Exercise \ref{exer1.1}}
\input{exer1.1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If the questions in subitems have longer than two columns but the solutions are short, may be for each questions in one column but solutions in two columns?

Comment: @somkiat_t answer updated